# Springsource Tools Suite thymeleaf tags are unknown

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, thymeleaf

I am usind Springsource Tools Suite and I want to develop a maven based web project. The parent archetype creator has used thymeleaf tags (th:block). It is working but I get warnings in STS that say: Unkown tag (th:block). How can i fix this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I cannot add comment, I will write it here:

Check three things:

1. Does maven contain thymeleaf dependencies?
   something like [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/2.1.2.RELEASE).
2. Do you have Thymeleaf resolver properly set:
   This is annotation example:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
       ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
       thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
       thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       return thymeleafViewResolver;
   }
   ```
3. Does your view have proper html tag:

   ```
   html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
   ```

Comment: I have this snippet in my WebMvcConfig

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

Comment: Please check number 3. If I take it out of my HTML page I get the same warning. Insert this in your html tag: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">, actually, only last part of it...(xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org")

Comment: I have no warnings when i replace the <html> tag with this one:
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="thymeleaf.org"> (i have deleted this ";", because it raised another warning) Thank you Blejzer!

Answer (score 0):

In case of HTML, DTD wan't be parsed.

Try using Eclipse plugin (remember to add Thymeleaf nature to project): https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin